# How to make an R function recognize arguments like 'past 30 days' for date arguments?

Tags: r, function

I realise that this is probably a really really basic question but I tried to find an answer online and I don't even think I'm looking for the right thing.

So I've just started learning R and I noticed some functions can take date arguments like 'past 30 days'. How does R know how to interpret that and if I create a new function, how do I make that function also recognize arguments like that?

Comment: From the package `lubridate`, there is a function called `is.Date` that will allow you to test if an object is a `Date`.

Comment: you can print those functions and see how the argument is handled. One example is `seq.Date` see how the function handles the `by` argument

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks for the tip! I wish I had thought of that. Yes, I figured it out, the function I was looking at was converting the string to a date inside the function. I just thought there was an existing function in some package that ppl regularly use. Anyway, thanks a lot. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that R does automatically nor is there any package that contains a function that converts strings in natural language like "last 2 months", "past year" etc to proper data ranges (as far as I know) so the functions I was looking at perform the conversion inside the function code.